# Low-cost long-range movement detection

Tags: phototransistor, motion

I have to design a circuit for a device to detect any motion in front of the device up to 2 meters. I have tried with IR reflection sensor, but couldn't achieve the range. Then, I found a [circuit on the internet](http://www.electronicsforu.com/electronicsforu/circuitarchives/view_article.asp?sno=219&article_type=1&title=Shadow&id=367#.U8S4v_mSznI) which works on passive detection of shadows.

So, basically it takes in the ambient light, and when there is a obstacle in front of the sensor, output is triggered.  As mentioned in the circuit about using L14F1 as sensor, I could not get that part where I am living. So, I used a a normal phototransistor with some black shielding around it. It seems to be working up to 40 cm.

1. Which type of sensor should I look for? What are the specifications that I need to look for this application (detect fast change in light up to 2 meters with narrow detection)?
2. My major problem is I do not know if this circuit works properly for fast light changes. I need to drive a DC motor at output for 5 sec whenever the sensor detects a movement up to 2 meters.
3. Is there any other kind of low-cost and effective sensor or method for this kind of application?

I am a beginner to this field. I am willing to learn by doing. So, any suggestions and advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The response of the transistor and the Op-Amp is very quick. The only "slow" aspect of this circuit is going to be the time-constant (51 seconds) designed for the output of the 555 timer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can rig a standard motion-activated light to work for you: add a lens or pipe in front of it so it looks only at the point you are interested in?

They work with a PIR sensor and a Fresnel lens, which focusses alternate parts of the field-of-interest on and off the sensor, so a movement from an 'on' part to and 'off' part or vice versa gives a large chance.

Comment: I just need to trigger an output when someone passes by the device. I have thought of PIR sensor before. But,I think PIR sensor would be expensive and also it has a wide angle of detection or??. how could i build a low cost detection circuit like the one used in this device

http://tronixstuff.com/tag/glade/

I want to build a similar device. So, it would be helpful if someone could suggest me a better option for this application

Comment: I can buy a motion-triggerd lamp in any hardware store for a few Euro's. If you consider that expensive.... As I suggested, the wide angle of detection can be reduced by a pipe and/or lens.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does "any motion" mean? What is moving, and how much motion constitutes a "trigger"?

Since your comments indicate that you can work with ambient light, a cheap USB camera and some software (such as [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), but that may be overkill) can be a remarkably effective solution.

Comment: I meant any movement in front of the device. like if a person passes by within a range of 2 metres. I think it would be expensive . I need a low cost solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an ultrasonic sensor. If by "motion" you mean human motion, you can use PIR sensors.

Answer (score 0):

[Elecfreaks PIR](http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/pir-motion-sensor-moduledypme003-p-156.html) ($3) and [Amazon PIR](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009BTHQ26) ($6)

I've used these PIR sensors in a few projects.  They are cheap, reliable, and easy to hook up.  As Wouter van Ooijen says in another answer, if you want to narrow the field of view use a cardboard tube.